# Functions of discrete and continuous RV's

Tags: probability-theory

I was just wondering, in the context of analytical probability, if we have a discrete RV X and any function f (which maps from R to R), will Y = f(X) be a discrete RV as well?

How about the continuous case? For any absolutely continuous RV X and continuous function f, will Y = f(X) be absolutely continuous? (Assume f maps from R to R like before).

Thank you! I'm not too clear how this works.

Comment: If $f$ is a  constant then f(X)$ is a constant r.v.

Answer (score 1):

Under suitable assumptions we have $\mu (Y^{-1}(E))=\mu (X^{-1}(f^{-1}(E))=\int_{f^{-1}(E)} h(x)d$ where $h$ is density of $X$. By a change of variable this gives $\mu (Y^{-1}(E))=\int_E h(f^{-1}(y)) (f^{-1}(y)'dy$. So $Y$ is absolutely continuous with density $h(f^{-1}(y)) (f^{-1}(y)')$.

[As already pointed out $Y$ need not have a density in  general. Continuity of $f$ is too weak for this].